# Run procedure only when system updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a procedure which uses reflection to get the current controller and actions in the system and updates the database with any new ones that do not exist already.

I have this running on an Index Action of the Admin Controller. I do not want to run this procedure every time the user clicks on the Admin dashboard but it needs to update the database when a system update occurs.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this? I am thinking down the lines of a version number or something that is checked before running and this version number gets updated in the database. Is there anyway to automatically increment a version number in the webconfig or something on every publish and how would this be checked in the system?

Thanks

Comment: What is "a system update"?  What are you actually updating in the database?

Comment: I have an MVC4 application which I publish and then copy the files to the server. I would save a version number in the database the app connects to

Comment: Why does this have to happen at runtime?  If all you're doing is telling the database that a new version has been deployed, this would be better to do as part of the deployment process itself, wouldn't it?

Comment: How would I do this on publishing an MVC4 project?

Comment: That entirely depends on how you're deploying it.  If it's a manual process then I imagine it would be another manual step in that process.  If it's scripted, then this would be another step in the script.  If the process is using some built-in functionality from Visual Studio then you'd have to use the Visual Studio tooling, perhaps as a post-deployment step in the project file somewhere?  (I'm not really familiar with Visual Studio deployments.)  It just seems like using reflection to somehow discern if function signatures have changed is a really roundabout way to update a version number.